# Symfony2 > MappingException: Class ...\Entity\User does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to get my user authentication working from the database. I have followed the instruction from the cookbook and set up a user entity. My bundle is registered in appKernel and I have used the bundle before. The only thing that changed is the new Entity\User.php and the changes in security.yml. I am sure that this is something silly, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. When I execute cache:clear, I get the following:

[image]

When browsing to app_dev.php:

[image]

Extract from app\src\MyFreelancer\PortalBundle\Entity\User.php

```
<?php
namespace MyFreelancer\PortalBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Ser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @Ser\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    * @Ser\Expose
    */
    private $id;
...
```

Extract from security.yml (which is causing the problem):

```
    providers:
    main:
        entity:
            class: MyFreelancer\PortalBundle\Entity\User,
            property: username
```

As you can see, the entity exists in the correct file structure, the namespace is defined in the entity file, the class is defined as an entity and the Bundle is registered. I do not know what I'm missing.

Comment: Remove the `,` at the end of config `class` line.

Comment: Ugh, I KNEW it was something stupid. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per jperovic's comment, it was just a case of removing the ',' from security.yml. Really silly mistake that I just didn't pick up on.